# How to get sum of rows of different id's at a time?

Tags: magento2, orders, sql

what would be possible query of in sql ?
if we want separate sum of each different item id's with multiple where clauses
like if we have a table persons :

```
-----------------
id | Amount
1 | 1.0
1 | 2.0
2 | 1.0
2 | 8.0
3 | 1.0
4 | 1.0
4 | 2.0
5 | 1.0
5 | 1.0
6 | 3.0
6 | 1.0
-----------------
```

i have wrote this but it doesn't works.

select sku , sum(qty_ordered) as total from sales_order_item

where sku = '86-0007-000072,86-0007-000073,44-0002-000137,83-0003-000045,44-0002-000124,83-0003-000046,44-0002-000182,44-0002-000134,44-0002-000132,304113,44-0002-000131,44-0002-000133,320146,44-0002-000217,0001-0001-000002'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code: `sum(qty_ordered) as total` seems just fine.

This one:

```
where sku = '86-0007-000072,86-0007-000073,44-0002-000137,83-0003-000045,44-0002-000124,83-0003-000046,44-0002-000182,44-0002-000134,44-0002-000132,304113,44-0002-000131,44-0002-000133,320146,44-0002-000217,0001-0001-000002'`
```

not so much.

You should do

```
where sku = '86-0007-000072' or sku = '86-0007-000073' or sku = '44-0002-000137'
```

and so on, for all of the skus that you need.

Shorter alternative for this is

```
where sku IN ('86-0007-000072','86-0007-000073','44-0002-000137')
```

Please note that to the `IN` you are sending an array of values. If you need to set the condition to be `sku` then you make sure that the values in this array are strings. If you need to set the condition to be, for example, `entity_id`, then make sure you send integers like

```
where entity_id IN (1436, 3632, 3453)
```

Comment: You are welcome.